# Split a string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How can I split string for 3 character? (I don't want to do loop for this, maybe some regular expression will be help)

I give example:

```
String str = "111222333444";
String[] result = str.split("help?"); // get "111", "222", "333"
```

Comment: *"I don't want.."*  Why should we care what you want?  It's what gets the job done, is what is important.

Comment: Why not do a loop?  It would be the fastest and simplest solution.

Comment: If I want to use loop, I don't need to ask on SO. I'm searching some nicer solution.. If it doesn't exist I use loop.

Comment: @nimus: regex solutions tend to be uglier rather than "nicer". Regexes are also slower, less readable and arguably harder to maintain. Are you asking this to get something done, or is it to learn about regexes?

Comment: you're serious or a joke ? I get some example.. I haven't idea what the string will be

Comment: @MAK - I though that it will be nicer then loop. But I couldn't find solution how do it with regular expression and I write here to learn something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [guava-library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
 Iterable<String> strNums = Splitter.fixedLength(3).split("111222333444")
```

Readable than using regex. You can then use `Ints.tryParse(...)` to get Integer version if you want.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know there is Splitter ... though it uses loops too :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `.split` will match regular expressions in the string which, in the underlying implementation, involves traversing the entire string anyway. Writing a simple loop to just create a token from every 3 characters would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I don't think you can do it for a string of undefined length, without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `split` because the arg of split is the separator, not the  resulting sub-strings.
So, your separator regex would be `nothing` !?

Sorry, you heve write loop. BTW, the regex engine for `split`is full of loops.